# What's the right way to implement refresh by pull down touch in the react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, refresh

I'm trying to implement a screen refresh like FlatList into React-Native,
but FlatList is not the right solution for complex views. FlatList is a good solution to implement lists with refresh, but I need to add a lot of views and those are not list.

So how can I implement refresh action without flat-list component ?

I should use that with one empty index ? or can I use other tricks ?

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @georgeawg I see, but I've not any code and as I said it's possible to use FlatList, but it's not comfortable, because I don't want to implement lists ...

Answer (score 1):

`FlatList` is a convenience wrapper around `VirtualizedList`, which inherits `ScrollView` props, therefore you can use [`refreshControl`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#refreshcontrol) prop to any of these *scrollable views* to create your *custom scrollable view* with `refreshControl`

```
state = {
  refreshing: false
}

_onRefresh = () => {
  this.setState({refreshing: true}, () => /* Handle changes and disable refreshing here*/);
}

<ScrollView
   refreshControl={
     <RefreshControl
       refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
       onRefresh={this._onRefresh}
     />
   }
  ...
 />
```